# To obtain a schengen a visa to Europe

Tags: visas, schengen

I live and work in Dubai. I earn less than AED 2000 per month. Is my monthly income sufficient to obtain Schengen visa to Europe?

Comment: Your income is not necessarily relevant when applying for a Schengen visa. What matters is how much funds (e.g. also savings) you dispose of.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply for a tourist visa, the officials try to determine if you are a genuine tourist or attempting to immigrate.

- Your savings and income are **part** of that question. You need enough savings to pay for your proposed itinerary and you need enough income to make spending that much on a mere vacation credible. Few people would spend a year's income on tourism, even if they had saved that much.
- Your job situation is **part** of that question. If you have a stable and well-paid job, they assume that you will return to it. Without a job, perhaps other documents can convince the officials that you will return.